# Calculate the number of possible paths from $(a, b)$ to $(c, d)$ which do not touch or cut the line $y = m$, where $b < m < d$.

Tags: coordinate-systems

> A particle moves only towards above or towards right in each step. For $a, b, c, d, m \in \mathbb{Z}$, calculate the number of possible paths from the point $(a, b)$ to $(c, d)$ which do not touch or cut the line $y = m$, where $b < m < d$.

---

I am stuck with the last property that's given, which is that $b < m < d$. Given that we can't cross $y=m$, this makes it impossible.

For example, take $(a,b)=(1,2)$, $y=4$, $(c,d)= (3,6)$

[image]

From the above diagram it's clear. Is this problem wrongly written or am I missing something here?

Comment: The condition sounds weird to me, too. The wording is very vague (i.e., what does it mean by "touch or cut"?), and any sensible interpretation of it seems to exclude all paths from $(a, b)$ to $(c, d)$.

Comment: I think the problem is wrongly written. Something like $x+y=m$ would make more sense imo.